# How to identify an element and invoke send_keys through selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```html
<img src="images/file_explorer.png" class="browse" style="cursor: pointer;height:33px;" title="file from your computer">
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.collabera.com/find-a-job/search-jobs/?sort_by=dateposted&Posteddays=4000&searchany=QA&anylocation=usa")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#srchpgbnnr > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div > a").click()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > section:nth-child(7) > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.col-md-offset-2.col-md-3.__jobdesc-sidebar.col-xs-hide > div > a").click()
time.sleep(15)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img.browse[src='images/file_explorer.png'][title='file from yourcomputer']").send_keys("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\collebra.txt")
```

url:https://www.collabera.com/find-a-job/search-jobs/job-details/126013-qa-analyst-jobs-ann-arbor-mi

my  code is above one its not working
how to find element in above upload button code

Comment: Are you sure you want to invoke `send_keys()` on a `<img>` tag?

Comment: can u edit errors in that above code please?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to click on an element in a iframe. Can you try to switch to iframe first and then click on upload icon?

Also windows file upload wizard is something you cannot handle with selenium (using send_keys()). You could windows shell scripting or python libraries (for example [PyAutoIt](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoIt/)) to handle the file upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To be able to handle file upload form you need to switch to iframe:

   ```
   driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_class_name("apply-form"))
   ```
2. You need to handle `input` element, but not `img`:

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\collebra.txt")
   ```

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type='file']"}

Comment: On which line? Did you use `time.sleep()` before that line?

Comment: thank you very much i am struggling for 3 days its worked

Comment: Great. But note that while it works with `time.sleep()` using `time.sleep()` is a bad practice, you should try [explicit/implicit waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: can u do me a favour how can i paste email and name next one in url :https://www.collabera.com/find-a-job/search-jobs/job-details/126013-qa-analyst-jobs-ann-arbor-mi

Comment: Try `driver.find_element_by_id("txtName").send_keys(name)`, `driver.find_element_by_id("txtEmail").send_keys(email)`

Answer (score 0):

To find the element and invoke `send_keys()` method you can discard the `time.sleep(5)` and induce *WebDriverWait* and use any of the following options :

- **CSS_SELECTOR** :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.browse[src='images/file_explorer.png'][title='file from your computer']"))).send_keys("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\collebra.txt")
  ```
- **XPATH** :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@class='browse' and @src='images/file_explorer.png' and @title='file from your computer']"))).send_keys("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\collebra.txt")
  ```

Comment: `not working` doesn't throws any light on whats wrong happening, update the question with your current code trial and error trace logs.